# Application to Make a 3D draw

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

Can you suggest me a program (app) to make a draw of a 3D pyramid, as shown in Figure 2 and Figure 3 in this paper ([paper](http://infolab.usc.edu/csci587/Fall2011/papers/The%20New%20Casper%20Query%20Processing%20for%20Location%20Services%20without%20Compromising%20Privacy.pdf))? I need to make something similar to this, and I am sure how they made it. I am sure that you - mathemeticians - might have used those kinds of app very often, so went here to ask for advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Inkscape. It's free, runs on Win and Linux and it is easy to use. You draw and export in pdf or eps, for example.

But if you like LaTeX, you can produce the code using TikZ.

ps: Inkscape has an extension to export in TikZ.